# Show data after query - Google Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-visualization

I have a data-table (in Google chart) and I want to send URL for connecting with my data-table and sending the query and after show the data in my page web, with JavaScript. 
How can I do it?

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function sendQuery(YYY)  {
           var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://localhost:8080/XXX-datasource/datasource?table=YYY');
           //query.setQuery('select zone_name, sum(cost) group by zone_name');
           console.log(query);

      }


    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is the output of `console.log(query);`?

Comment: I have this error : ( [14:37:43,774] L'utilisation des « Mutation Events » est obsolète. Utiliser « MutationObserver » à la place. @ chrome://y2layers/content/overlay.js:242 ) and ([14:37:47,493] SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data) and ([14:37:47,887] uncaught exception: Not a valid URL: http://localhost/test_new/newnew.html)

Comment: Oh, well why don't for format that error, and put it in your question. it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data source on your server is compatible with the Visualization API Queries, you would use something like this https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#using_the_query_language, substituting your own url, select statement, and chart code.